# TEmbeddedWB & Console

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, twebbrowser

When I tried to compile EmbeddedWB in Console it complains about some OleCtrls unit. Yet normal Webbrowser compiles without no problem.

How to compile it under Console?

`[dcc64 Fatal Error] SHDocVw_EWB.pas(66): F1026 File not found: OleCtrls.dcu'`

Comment: Define `complain`? What error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is [unit scope names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names). A console application by default has different unit namespace aliases from a forms application. Solve the problem by either:

1. Using fully qualified unit names. The full name for that unit is Vcl.OleCtrls.
2. Add missing unit scope names (in your case Vcl) to your console application's [project configuration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler).

Since you are compiling third party code, it will be preferable for you not to modify that third party code. Hence option 2 is the way forward.

There may be other unit scope names that are needed. Make sure you add them all. And make sure that you are using the latest source for the component, obtained from the VCS repo and double check that it does indeed support XE4.

Note that my assumption is that by *console* you mean a console application. If you actually mean command line compilation then the answer is still essentially the same. You'll need to make sure that the unit scope names are specified when compiling. Normally that would be done in the project configuration and msbuild would pick them up and pass them on to dcc32 or dcc64.

Comment: Mainly because of this `Windows.SetParent(WindowHandle, Forms.Application.Handle);`

Comment: Read my answer again. Carefully. Note that I offer two options. Option 2 will mean that code will compile.

Comment: The other issue is that to make the code work (as opposed to compile as per this question), you'll need a message pump and a hidden parent window, I guess. But this question is about compilation. Please let it not morph into downstream debugging.

Comment: So add the unit scope names to the configuration like I said. Make sure you add them to the **base** configuration.

Comment: I've updated the source code for XE4. I can upload it somewhere for people with the same problem. :)

Comment: What were the problems then?

Comment: Well it works now in 32 bit Console. But 64 bit is throwing `FLOAT DIVIDE BY ZERO` errors. :)
The problem were namespaces. Such as JPEG, Forms etc.

Comment: You really don't need to change the source code. You've gone for option 1. Option 2 is better. And are you sure you've got the latest from the vcs repo? I'd expect the latest version to handle unit scope names.

Comment: Floating point errors are easy to fix. IE expects to be run with floating point exceptions masked. But Delphi clears the exception masks. Simply mask exceptions and it's all good. There are countless questions on that topic here, many with answers from me!!

Comment: I've fixed the floating exceptions like this.. `SetExceptionMask([exInvalidOp, exDenormalized, exZeroDivide, exOverflow, exUnderflow, exPrecision]);` however there are occasional COM errors such as `$C0000005 with message c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION`

Comment: Well, they are too general to debug from here with no code. Sorry!

Comment: I create TEmbeddedWB like this
`Browser:= TEmbeddedWB.CreateParented(HWND(HWND_MESSAGE));
    Browser.Visible:=False;
    Browser.HandleNeeded;`

Comment: This cannot be debugged in comments. Make an SSCCE and post a new question. HWND_MESSAGE can't be used as a parent surely. That's got to be wrong. And did you call CoInitialize?

Comment: Thanks! It seems `CoInitialize` was the key! Well `HWND_MESSAGE` runs just fine.. If it ain't broke don't fix it!!

Comment: Good. Three problems solved for the price of one! You got a good deal there!  ;-)

Comment: A bit late but still. What do you think about this [MessagePump](http://pastebin.com/eVCYzWqk)

Comment: It's riddled with problems. I won't attempt to debug it in comments. I've already gone the extra mile here I think. Time for a new topic.